# How do I modify a text file in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem. How do I modify a text file in Python?

Here is my code:

```
(with open "clues.txt")
y = content.readlines
```

Comment: That's not valid python code. You should, perhaps, google a little bit more. StackOverflow answers specific technical questions, for broad introductions there's the rest of the internet :)

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: @user3449341 To start with, that's not Python code. Please check out the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: Python files for beginners: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open it in write mode or append mode.

```
with open("clues.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("your text")
```

going through python docs help u much more http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html